# Use an custom posttype as my hompage in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have an wordpress page that uses custom posttypes, the custom posttype in the case is named "work", now what i want is when the visitor lands on the website it sees a specifik post of this "custom posttype" handeld by the template that handles this custom posttype.

so basically open a specifik custom posttype as homepage.

how can i arrange this?

Comment: create a custom template and display posts for that by custom code you can use plugins   after that   you can user this as your front page  fron reading bt choosing option front page .

Answer (score 0):

1) create a template e.g. 'work-posts' which loops and shows all posts of 'work type'
2) go to settings>reading:
   a) select option in front page displays in 'static page' as your template name 'work-posts'